# sql - Relate fields from diff. databases to a single field

Tags: sql

Is it possible to relate 2 or more "id_numbers" from different tables, to a single "username" from a single table (accounts)?

I am relating the faculty "id_number" to the accounts, but it says "relationship already exists". Do i need different field names? Or what i am doing is not posssible? Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It's not really related to PHP.

Comment: edited. sorry for the mislead